# Scanner only reads the first input

Tags: java

apart from the program only reading in the first value, i have 12 inputs while its saying that i have 11 after iv counted all the inputs

this is my input data

```
Edwards                 Steven                  (356)153-9460
Carter                  Joshua                  (290)261-7625
Carter                  Joshua                  (761)321-9457
Jackson                 Anthony                 (724)091-7819
Carter                  Barbara                 (759)301-3133
Evans                   Edward                  (072)023-0203
White                   Christopher             (060)075-3782
White                   Christopher             (060)075-3782
Taylor                  Michelle                (369)348-9660
Baker                   Melissa                 (844)824-5853
Young                   Anthony                 (692)839-8466
Hall                    Michael                 (216)386-2922
```

code

```
class PhonebookEntry {

    private Name name;
    private PhoneNumber phonenumber;


    public PhonebookEntry(Name name, PhoneNumber phonenumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber; 
    }

    public Name getname() {return name;}
    public PhoneNumber getnumber() {return phonenumber;}
    public void call() {

         if (phonenumber.isTollFree()) {
            System.out.println("Dialing (toll-free) "+name+": "+phonenumber);

         }
        else
            System.out.println("Dialing "+ name.getFormal()+ ": ("+phonenumber.getAreaCode() +")"
            + phonenumber.getExchange()+"-" + phonenumber.getLineNumber());
            System.out.println();
    }
    public String tostring() {return name +":"+ phonenumber;}

     public static  PhonebookEntry read(Scanner scanner) {
        if(!scanner.hasNext())  return null;{

         Name name = new Name(scanner.next(), scanner.next());
         PhoneNumber phonenumber = new PhoneNumber(scanner.next());

         return new PhonebookEntry(name,phonenumber);
        }

     }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("phonebook.text"));
        PhonebookEntry prevEntry =null;
        int count =0;
        PhonebookEntry entry = (read(scanner));
        while(read(scanner) != null) {


             if(prevEntry != null) {
                 if(prevEntry.equals(entry))
                     System.out.println("Duplicate phone book entry"+ '"'+entry.name+": "+ entry.phonenumber+'"'+ "discovered");

                 else if(prevEntry.name.equals(entry.name) && !prevEntry.phonenumber.equals(entry.phonenumber)) {
                     System.out.println("Warning duplicate name encountered " + '"' + entry.name +":"+entry.phonenumber+ '"' + " discovered");

                 }

             }
             count++;
             System.out.println( "phone book entry: "+entry.name + ": "+ entry.phonenumber);
             prevEntry = entry;
            entry.call();

        }

        System.out.println( count+" phonebook entries processed.");

        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
PhonebookEntry entry = (read(scanner));
while(read(scanner) != null) {
```

should be something like

```
PhonebookEntry entry;
while((entry = read(scanner)) != null) {
```

Which is why you only get the first entry. You never updated `entry` in subsequent `read`(s). Also, your `tostring` should be `toString` and this is a good time to suggest the `@Override` annotation to catch that in future.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name +":"+ phonenumber;
}
```

Comment: yes it worked but i fail to understand why mine didn't work

instantiated the entry of type phonebookentry but with entry nor read(scanner) would work on its own, why is it that when they are put together they work?

Comment: @AliAhmad Because you didn't change `entry`. Every loop, read something, was it `null`? Don't update `entry`. That's the **only** difference between the code. Mine `read`s, updates `entry` and ***then*** checks for `null`.

Comment: ah ok i get it, while mine just kept sending the same thing over and over, it lacked the updating , thanks alot

Comment: one other thing if you would be so kind to help me with in the part where i try to match the pervious entry with the present it doesnt give me the message that a "duplicate phone book entry ........" and while i want it to read that instead of the duplicate following

Comment: @AliAhmad See what I did with `toString()`? You need to do that with `equals(Object)`. As is, you only compare reference identity.

Comment: i have 2 classes where the equals methods are within the same package, is that substantial enough or do i need to create another equals methods with the Boolean comparison as well?

Comment: @AliAhmad When you say `prevEntry.equals(entry)` for that to work, `PhonebookEntry` **must** override `Object.equals(Object)`.

Comment: yeah i implemented the equals method and now it displays the message if it is a duplicate but i still dont know how to tell the program, dont print the duplicate input

Comment: Add a `continue;` to the end of the `if` block to skip the rest of the current iteration.